# Calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Help! new to calculated columns although getting the hang of it I have 6 columns which will contain a value, I what to average the total figure divided by the number of columns but I want to exclude columns containing 0 and I am struggling! a lot!

In Excel I can do this by;

```
=SUM(E6:E11)/SUMPRODUCT(N(E6:E11<>0),N(LEN(E6:E11)>0))
```

or

```
=AVERAGEIF(E6:E11,">0.1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a fixed number of columns, this is a cinch.

```
=(Value1+Value2+Value3+Value4+Value5+Value6)/(IF(Value1=0, 0, 1) + IF(Value2=0, 0, 1) + IF(Value3=0, 0, 1) + IF(Value4=0, 0, 1) + IF(Value5=0, 0, 1) + IF(Value6=0, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Do I assume value is my column name?

Comment: Correct, substitute the value# fields with your columns

Comment: It works!!! thank you very much I really appreciate it, do you know how long I have been trying to work this out!!!

Comment: Feel free to nominate as an answer. :)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: There's a checkbox next to the vote up/down buttons on the answer. Tick that and you've recorded this answer as the one that you've accepted.